# How to extract a list of data in a row ignoring blanks (Excel 2013)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a range of data in multiple rows, for example B:G; A is the Header.
Some cells in the range are blank:

```
     |   A    |   B    |   C    |   D   |    E    |    F   |    G   |  
  1  | HEADER |        | Green  |       |  Blue   |        |        |
```

I need a formula to copy all the values into another place, consequently, starting from B, ignoring the blank cells:

```
     |   A    |   B    |   C    |   D   |    E    |    F   |    G   |  

  2  | HEADER | Green  | Blue   |       |         |        |        |
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 2013, the following array formula should work:

```
I1: =INDEX($A1:$G1,1,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(LEN($A1:$G1)>0)*COLUMN($A1:H$1),COLUMN(INDEX($1:$1,1):INDEX($1:$1,COUNTA($A1:$G1)))))
```

The `AGGREGATE` function returns an array of the column numbers that contain data (and the function has an argument to exclude errors, so we don't return the empty columns), and the `INDEX` function returns the value in those columns.

*In Excel 2013, you may need to "confirm" this **array-formula** (**after selecting** `I1:O1`) by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar, and you should see all the results*

You can then fill down as far as needed.

[image]

***NOTE** If you don't want to use a CSE formula, you can use the INDEX function to return each element of the array. eg:*

```
I1: =IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX($A1:$G1,1,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(LEN($A1:$G1)>0)*COLUMN($A1:H$1),COLUMN(INDEX($1:$1,1):INDEX($1:$1,COUNTA($A1:$G1))))),COLUMNS($A:A)),"")
```

Fill right to `O1`.  Then select `I1:O1` and fill down as far as needed.

Comment: Thanks Ron. I used your formula, of course with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. But the formula repeats the header from I:O. I don't know how can I add a screenshot to the comment, but I made a sample table exactly like your screenshot. Do you have any idea, what my mistake might be?

Comment: @Solarinoos I have edited my answer to show a non-CSE formula that should work if you can't figure out the CSE function.

Comment: @Solarinoos So far as what your mistake might be, I'm guessing that you didn't enter the array formula properly (but I don't have an excel version to test that on). As I recall, you need to enter the formula in a single cell, while having multiple cells selected.  Then CSE. There's more specific information on the MS Help pages as to how to enter array formulas in the older versions of Excel.

Comment: Your second comment pointed exactly to my mistake: "...enter the formula in a single cell, while having multiple cells selected". Now the array formula works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you use latest version of Excel, you can use FILTER function:

`=FILTER(A1:G1,A1:G1<>"")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Máté, but I am using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You may use "Go To" to select non-empty cells.

Select the cells from B1 to G1 > Press Ctrl+G > Specilal > Check the box of Constants > OK. Then copy non-emptu cells to Row 2.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Emily, but I need to do it with formula. The "Go To" solution works only for one row and not multiple rows. I have about 400 rows.